# unmet dependencies while installing Ros on Ubuntu

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring) x64 with a virtual machine

I run:

```
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
```

I get:

```
  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-desktop-full : Depends: ros-hydro-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-mobile but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-perception but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have followed every step on the ros wiki (from allowing  "restricted," "universe," and "multiverse." to updating the index)

I have also checked other solutions and many of them suggested using aptitude, still I couldn't use aptitude since I had errors while installing its package.

If you need more details let me know.

Help me !

Thanks :)

[UPDATE]

It's just that ROS Hydro didn't work out with ubuntu 13.04 due to its instability I guess.  I recommend you guys, if you have this problem, to switch to a more stable ubuntu distribution (12.04 LTS worked just fine with me)

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202687/unmet-dependencies-while-installing-ros-on-ubuntu/) by [Dayire](https://answers.ros.org/users/21582/dayire/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a package conflict at a lower level. You'll need to recursively try each dependency which complains until you find the lowest level conflict and resolve that.

apt-get is surprisingly unhelpful doing this. Each time you get an error like that try to explicitly install each of the Depends entries, until you find the problem when it gives a useful error message.

You can use
`sudo apt-get install -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes <package>` to get more details from apt.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0